# What does set_if_nil.call do in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm relatively new to ruby and have some legacy code to support.  In it is the following line that I don't understand:

```
set_if_nil.call(:type, @config['type_1'])
```

I assume it it setting the type variable to to the value of `@config['type_1']`, but why the call method as well?  Also, there is no type variable in the class.  The method this is in is passed an object.  Is this a parameter of that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `set_if_nil` is defined as a Proc. If it is, then the `call` method executes that Proc, passing in `:type` and `@config...` as parameters.

AFAIK, `set_if_nil` is not defined as part of a Ruby standard library, so to understand more details about what's happening you'll have to track down where it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

I found some similar method calls on [github](https://github.com/search?l=ruby&q=set_if_nil&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93), which looks like your example, one is something like this:

```
def set_if_nil(attr, value)
  write_attribute(attr, value) if read_attribute(attr).nil?
end
```

`write_attribute` is part of active_record, and it "sets" an attribute value. So, think about this: (this is not the actual active-record code, but for easily understanding)..

```
class A
  def initialize
    @attributes = {}
  end

  def set_if_nil(attr, value)
    write_attribute(attr, value) if read_attribute(attr).nil?
  end

  def read_attribute(attr)
    @attributes[attr]
  end

  def write_attribute(attr, value)
    @attributes[attr] = value
  end

  def do_some_stuff
    set_if_nil(:type, "default-type")
  end
end

a = A.new
a.do_some_stuff
a.read_attribute(:type) # => "default-type"

a.write_attribute(:type, "my-type")
a.do_some_stuff
a.read_attribute(:type) # => "my-type"
```

There are other `set_if_nil` implementations [like this one](https://github.com/sprestage/ranch-tracks/blob/ab797035ba70a7cc1cff2c39359c6a914a090d44/lib/tracks/attribute_handler.rb#L24-L26), that behave exactly the same:

```
def set_if_nil(key, value)
  @attributes[key.to_sym] ||= value
end
```

Also, stackoverflow is mostly for helping people with specific problems, not learning new languages. If you don't understand a project code, consider asking the project maintainers instead of here, it would be easier even to you.